# Custom logo is not reflecting in SP 2010 custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, site-logo

Am trying to add a custom logo in my SP 2010 master page's `div` tag.
Below is my part of master page code:

```
                 <!-- site logo -->
                    <div id="v5-site-logo">
                        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" 
            NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/" 
                  id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
                            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage 
          name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" 
          LogoImageUrl="/Style Library/Images/custom_logo.png" 
                 runat="server"/>
                        </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
                    </div>
```

But its not reflecting correctly on my page's top left hand corner.I need to fix this.

Referred Kyle Schaeffer's `v5.master`
  [here](http://kyleschaeffer.com/mobile/v5-responsive-html5-master-page/)

- Also, need to know how to add a Home link on the top navigation.Currently,by default my sub sites are displayed on the top navigation as hyperlinks. Can I modify the master page such a way that,I can add a home link with a nice image,so that end users can have a smooth navigation.